# Highlight all upper case words in VIM

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc file, I added

```
match Title /EXAMPLE/
```

so when I type EXAMPLE, this word is highlighted, it works fine, and my question is, how do I highlight all upper case letter? not just EXAMPLE, but everything else too.

```
--> THIS IS AN EXAMPLE
--> SECOND EXAMPLE
--> ETC
```

I want to highlight something like the sentences above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do something like this

```
match Title /[A-Z]/
```

This will highlight all uppercase letters

Comment: to higlight only words with 2 or more letters try `match Title /[A-Z]\{2,\}/`

Answer (score 5):

this should work for words in all uppercase

```
:syn match Error "\v<[A-Z]+>"
```